Generalized dimension property for rings
My question is very basic, I am looking for a characterization (and name) of rings $R$ satisfying the following property $\star$.
For any $V, W$ two finitely generated $R$-modules such that $V\oplus W\simeq V $ implies that $W=0$.
Any field or the ring of integers has this property.
What if $R=\mathbb{Z}[G] $ is a group ring, under which condition on $G$, $R$ satisfies the property $\star$.
Added later: I will be happy if there is an answer to my question in case when the group $G$ is free and finitely generated. I guess it will give a hint to other cases.
Edit As it was mentioned in the comments, It seems that if $R$ is an integral group ring, then it has the property $\star$ under the additional condition that $V$ is finitely generated projective $R$-module.

More generally, this is implied by noetherian. Indeed for a counterexample, $V$ is not Hopfian (isomorphic to a proper quotient), hence non-noetherian.

More generally any such ring has to satisfy IBN ($\mathbb Z[G]$ does satisfy this for every $G$ but that isn't the end of the story yet I guess.)  I can't remember if I've seen this property specifically...  It seems like a very natural cancellation result to base a definition on.

I would recommend having a read of the following remarks on the IBN property https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82570195.pdf. In particular on page 4
it is noted that your condition holds for all group algebras over fields of ℎ=0
(and so integral group rings by tensoring) provided
is a f.g free module. This then extends also to the case that
is f.g projective. One might hope that this would extend to all f.g modules as you’ve asked, but this is not immediately clear to me.

@WilliamThomas Thank you for the reference! It solves the case when R is an integral group ring and V is a finitely generated projective R-module! But I still interested when V is finitely generated but not necessarily projective. Any further indication in this direction are highly appreciated.
